# Having trouble overriding a virtual method declared with template parameter pack expansion

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, virtual-functions, variadic-functions

I'm having trouble overriding a virtual method of the base class specified using template parameter pack expansion - while the overriding method will exhibit the actual relevant types. Here's an MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename... Ts>
class A { virtual void foo(Ts&&...); };

class B : public A<int, unsigned> {
    void foo(int x, unsigned y) override { std::cout << "here"; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
}
```

Compiling this (with standard set to either C++11 or C++14), I get:

> ```
> a.cpp:9:7: error: ‘void B::foo(int, unsigned int)’ marked override, but does not override
>   void foo(int x, unsigned y) override {
>        ^
> ```

Comment: Look carefully on the signature of the base class's function.

Answer (score 7):

The base class's function signature is `void foo(Ts&&...);`.

The derived class's function signature is `void foo(int x, unsigned y)`.

See anything different between the two? The difference is `&&`. In order to match the base class's function signature, you need the derived class to use `void foo(int&& x, unsigned&& y)`.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/12n1R9):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Ts>
struct A { virtual void foo(Ts&&...) {} };

struct B : A<int, unsigned> {
    void foo(int&& x, unsigned&& y) override { std::cout << "here"; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.foo(1, 2u);
}
```

Comment: What version of clang are you on, your code works fine on 3.7 : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5695318de3b879c9 And for your example, i think you did a common mistake, with template T&& is an universal reference, but only if the template arguments are direclty related to the template function. Here, Ts&&... match only rvalue references.

Comment: Of course it doesn't link, where's the definition for `A::foo();`?